# Socket.io being disconnected and connected when joining a room

Tags: node.js, socket.io, express-handlebars

***it worked fine with out joining a room***
a list of friends is displayed and on click, a new page is opened for chatting for individual friends

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>

    </tr>
    {{#each friends}}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="/chat?name={{this.profileName}}">{{this.profileName}}</a></td>

    </tr>
    {{/each}}
  </table>
```

then on chat_server.js where socket.io resides

```
socket.join(chatTable);//joining a room ! where problem rises

io.sockets.in(chatTable).emit('db chat message',rows);
```

then on web side

```
 <form action="">
  <input id="m" autocomplete="off" /><button>Send</button>
</form>
```

and on the jquery portion

```
 $('form').submit(function(){

  socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
   $('#m').val()='';
  return false;
});
```

when joining a room is invoked... the page is refreshed with the url parameter(name) being gone and the socket.io being disconnected and reconnected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume the `chatTable` variable is a [string](https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#socket-join-room-callback).

Use `event.preventDefault()`:

```
 $('form').submit(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();
    socket.emit('chat message', $('#m').val());
    $('#m').val("");//$('#m').val()=' ' ; does not work 
});
```

Also, check the [Socket.IO cheatsheet](https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/#) and the docs of [rooms and namespaces](https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#).

Comment: the event.preventDefault() method is stopping the page refresh and it's working!, but the text in the input is not being cleared by the $('m').val() = ' '; method

Comment: Bad syntax, it should be $('#m').val('');